# Lower incomplete gamma function format in series representation and R

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, gamma-distribution, sum

1. As known that the lower incomplete gamma function can be written as $\gamma(a,x) = x^{a}e^{-x}\sum_k^\infty{{x^{k}}\over a^{k+1}}.$ What is the format for  $\sum_j^\infty{\gamma(v/p-j,rx^{p})} $ in series representation? (where $v$, $p$ and $r$ are parameters)
2. $\gamma(a,x)$ in R is zipfR::Igamma(a, x, lower=TRUE, log=FALSE). If $\sum_j^\infty{\gamma(v/p-j,rx^{p})} $, what is the $a$ and $b$ should be in Igamma()?

Comment: You probably mean $\gamma(a,x) = x^a e^{-x} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{\Gamma(a+k+1)/\Gamma(a) } $ note that the summation is specified as $ \sum_{k=0}^\infty$ instead of  $\sum_{k}^\infty$, and probably your term $a^{k+1}$ is not right.

Comment: You are looking for the sum $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \gamma(v/p-j,rx^p)$. Based on your earlier question I guess that this relates to the generalized incomplete gamma function introduced by Chaudhry and Zubair. For this you should use: $$\gamma(a,x;b) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-b)^k}{k!} \gamma(a-k,x) $$ it will be different in your case with other parameters, but the absence of a term like $\frac{(-b)^k}{k!} $ is strange.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about the generalized incomplete gamma function that you mention in [an earlier question](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042798000314), then note that the path you try to follow here has been done before (I have now added this also to my previous answer to your previous question):

[Miller, Allen R., and Ira S. Moskowitz. "On certain generalized incomplete gamma functions." *Journal of computational and applied mathematics 91.2 (1998): 179-190*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042798000314)

They eventually express the function in terms of a [Kampé de Fériet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamp%C3%A9_de_F%C3%A9riet_function) (a two-variable generalization of the generalized hypergeometric series)

> $$\begin{array}{rl} \Gamma \left( -v, \frac{1}{x};\frac{z^2}{4} \right) = &  \Gamma\left( - v , \frac{1}{x} \right) \Gamma(1+c) \left( \frac{2}{z} \right)^v I_v(z) \\ & - \frac{z^2}{4} \frac{x^{1+v}}{1+v} e^{-1/x}   F \mathstrut_{2:0;0}^{0:2;1}
>     \left[
>       \begin{array}{ r r r  }
>         \dfrac{\phantom{2,2+v}}{\phantom{2,2+v}}  : & 
>           1,1+v  ; &
>           1 ;  \\ 
>        2, 2+v : &
>           \dfrac{\phantom{1,1+v}}{\phantom{1,1+v}}  ; &
>           \dfrac{\phantom{1}}{\phantom{1}}  ; &
>       \end{array} 
>       -x \dfrac{z^2}{4}, \dfrac{z^2}{4}
>     \right] \end{array}$$
>       where now $v \neq -1, -2, -3, ...$

and for non negative integers

> $$\begin{array}{rl} \Gamma \left( n, x; z \right) = &
>    \frac{(-z)^n}{n!} \lbrace \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-n)_k}{z^k} \Gamma(k,x) + _0F_1[-;n+1;z]\Gamma(0,x)  \\& - \frac{z}{n+1} \frac{e^{-x}}{x}   F
>  \mathstrut_{2:0;0}^{0:2;1}
> \left[
>   \begin{array}{ r   r r  }
> \dfrac{\phantom{2,n+2}}{\phantom{2,2+v}}  : & 
>   1,1  ; &
>   1 ;  \\ 
>    2, n+2 \;: &
>   \dfrac{\phantom{1,1}}{\phantom{1,1}}  ; &
>   \dfrac{\phantom{1}}{\phantom{1}}  ; &
>   \end{array} 
>   -x^{-1} z, z
> \right]  \rbrace \end{array}$$